# How to hide the Horizontal box using pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Here in my sample program i want to hide the hbox.but i couldn't find any method to hide hbox in pyqt4.Can any one please help me how to hide the horizontal box.Thank you in advance.

Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
global payments
payments = False
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        self.cash = QtGui.QPushButton("cash")
        self.card = QtGui.QPushButton("card")
        self.wallet = QtGui.QPushButton("wallet")
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.cash)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.card)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.wallet)
        self.paybtn = QtGui.QPushButton("pay")
        self.paybtn.clicked.connect(self.show_payments)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.paybtn,1,0)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500,500)
        self.show()

    def show_payments(self):
        global payments
        payments = not payments
        print payments
        if payments:
            self.paybtn.setText('Edit Order')
            self.grid.addLayout(self.hbox,0,0)

        else:
            self.paybtn.setText('Pay')
            #here i want to hide the self.hbox


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function of the layouts is to manage the positions and sizes of other widgets, your task is not to hide. Instead you must create a widget where the hbox is with the buttons and that widget set it in the grid layout, so it is only necessary to hide or show the new widget.

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500,500)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.foo_widget = QtGui.QWidget(visible=False)
        self.foo_widget.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, 
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.foo_widget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.cash = QtGui.QPushButton("cash")
        self.card = QtGui.QPushButton("card")
        self.wallet = QtGui.QPushButton("wallet")

        hbox.addWidget(self.cash)
        hbox.addWidget(self.card)
        hbox.addWidget(self.wallet)

        self.paybtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Pay", clicked=self.show_payments)

        grid.addWidget(self.foo_widget, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.paybtn, 1, 0)

    def show_payments(self):
        global payments
        payments = not payments
        self.paybtn.setText('Edit Order' if payments else 'Pay')
        self.foo_widget.setVisible(payments)
```